# block acting as inline block?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently building a website and my dropdown navbar isn't working correctly. When I hover over each element on the navbar, the dropdown menu drops as should, but the elements are blocked inline even though my CSS has them assigned as a normal block.

Here is my code as it follows:

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar ul li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  height: 68px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:focus {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-sub {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-sub a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-sub a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.navbar ul li:hover .nav-sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml">
      <img src="~/Content/Pictures/CuttingEdgeWhite.png" style=" width: 200px; height: 50px;" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Electrical</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Lighting</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Energy</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">National Accounts</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Contact Us</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Service Request</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Careers</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I've seen that having a parent element float left doesn't allow inline-block to work properly, but I have no idea of how to get around that. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fix float solution

This is the quickest solution, there is a greedy rule in your CSS:

> ```
> .navbar ul li {
>   float: left;
> }
> ```

The problem with this rule is that effects the dropdown list as well. To fix this change to:

```
.navbar > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
```

### Flexbox solution

- Set both ul lists with `display: flex` this avoids using floats.
- Removed all `float` from the elements
- Set the drop-down ul list with `flex-direction: column`, this way it displays vertically.

Take a look at the following example:

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.logo {
  padding: 15px;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  height: 68px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:focus {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-sub {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-sub ul {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-sub a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-sub a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.navbar ul li:hover .nav-sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml">
      <img src="~/Content/Pictures/CuttingEdgeWhite.png" style=" width: 200px; height: 50px;" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Electrical</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Lighting</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Energy</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">National Accounts</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Contact Us</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Service Request</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Careers</a>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! That worked perfectly. I had a budding suspicion it was something incredibly simple. Out of curiosity, what difference exactly does adding in the > make? In case you couldn't tell, I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: You are welcome @WilliamBuxton . Regarding `>` stands for **child combinator**, you can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors): *"It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the children of elements matched by the first."* Remember to accept the answer and vote in case you feel the answer matches your expectations, more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

They aren't acting as inline blocks, they are acting as floating elements … because you are floating them.

> ```
> .navbar ul li {
>   float: left;
> }
> ```

Don't float them if you want them arranged vertically.

```
.navbar > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Noticing the same and editing my answer by the time you posted the same :/ But this is the shortest path...